# Automatically call class method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

my situation:

- a dashboard controller who register the widgets inside it and automatically builds the view.
- widget classes that are going to populate the dashboard, who adopt `<widget>` protocol(some informal methods required), and need to be registered in the dashboard class so the dashboard singleton knows who wants to be in.
- the dashboard class has `+(void)register:(Class<widget>)w;` that simply register the classes who wants to be in in an NSArray

I need each widget class to call automatically that method.in c++ i used to make a boolean static variable that i would initialize with that method.
Language = objective-c

Comment: please use proper formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The objective-c runtime will call two methods when a class is first loaded. `+load` and `+initialize`. I believe what you want could be done by calling `[self register]` from within `+initialize`.

Comment: `+initialize` is only called when the class is *used*, not when it is loaded. Since the program most likely doesn't know about the class until it is registered, `+load` would be more appropriate.

Comment: so the solution is just overriding that method?

Comment: It really depends on exactly what register is supposed to be doing. I find the whole architecture described about to be...bad

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg what is your suggestion for my problem?I know it seems not a good practise but my solution builds code that doesnt need to be edited for new types of widgets

Comment: You don't describe enough for me to give you a valid alternative. But within what you said you're doing, implementing +load in the classes you want to register with the singleton should work.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg my singleton must know in a manner which classes are going to be showed(the dashboard is building icons for each controller).I dont want to instatiate objects for memory reasons.This was a solution i imported from my c++ experience, but i am quite new in obj-c dev and would be really happy with new solutions!

Comment: @palominoz: In general, the best solution I've found is to have some object responsible for loading the relevant widgets, and it will be the one that registers them.

Comment: I would agree with Chuck, having classes register in their +load is kinda weird in Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

A way you could do it is with the runtime:

1. Grab a list of all the classes known to the runtime.
2. Iterate the list, and check to see if the class conforms to your widget protocol
3. If it does conform to the protocol, invoke the `+register:` method or whatever

Regarding step #2, you can't use the `+conformsToProtocol:` method, because one of the classes you'll iterate is the `NSZombie` class, which triggers an exception whenever you invoke a method on it.  Thus, you'd want to use the [`class_conformsToProtocol()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW17) runtime function instead.